# change object property to match values in given array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Heres my app structure

Codepen Example : https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-blackwell-kd3nn

```
class MasterForm extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      userInput: "",
      available: "",
      silos: []
    };
  }

  handleFormSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.silo_1Lookup();
  };

  handleInputChange = e => {
    let input = e.target;
    let name = e.target.name;
    let value = input.value;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  silo_1Lookup = () => {
    let silos = [...this.state.silos];

    silos.push({
      userInput: this.state.userInput,
      available: this.state.available
    });

    this.setState({
      silos,
      userInput: "",
      available: ""
    });

    const siloDepthFilling = {
      "0": "926",
      "0.5": "893",
      "1": "860",
      "1.5": "827",
      "2": "794",
      "2.5": "761",
      "3": "728",
      "3.5": "695",
      "4": "662",
      "4.5": "629",
      "5": "595"
    };
    console.log("function ran");
    return siloDepthFilling[silos[0].userInput];
  };
}
```

I'm trying to change the property of silos[0].available to match the content inside of my silo_1Lookup() function.

For example, if the user enters 5, silos[0].available should be set to "595"

```
if (silos[0].userInput === '5') {
 return silos[0].available = "595"
}
```

kinda like that but using the dictionary inside silo_1Lookup();

At the moment, the function runs, but silos[0].available is not being updated with a new value, and there is no error message

Comment: Looks like you are not calling `setState()` after calling `silo_1Lookup()`.

Comment: @Nikhil where should it be? I've moved it to the bottom of my silo_1lookup() but still doesn't work

Comment: Check out my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57898783/2924577.

Comment: in the handler, you have to call silo_1Lookup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not updating the state after changing `available` value.

In your function, call `setState()` after making required changes.

You are using `silos` to display both `userInput` and `available`. So updating `silos` is what changes the view, not `available`.

```
silo_1Lookup = () => {

    const siloDepthFilling = {
      "0": "926",
      "0.5": "893",
      "1": "860",
      "1.5": "827",
      "2": "794",
      "2.5": "761",
      "3": "728",
      "3.5": "695",
      "4": "662",
      "4.5": "629",
      "5": "595"
    };
    console.log("function ran");

    let available = siloDepthFilling[this.state.userInput];

    let silos = [...this.state.silos];

    silos.push({
      userInput: this.state.userInput,
      available: available
    });

    this.setState(
      {
        silos: silos,
        available: available
      }
    );
  };
```

Also, you are not using `key` for your list items and it is throwing an error. Make following changes to your `Table` component.

```
{silos.map((silo, i) => {
     return (
        <tr key={i.toString()}>
           <td>{silo.userInput}</td>
           <td>{silo.available}</td>
        </tr>
      );
 })}
```

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-jennings-wlw8j

Comment: this is what I initially tried after reading your comment, however available remains unchanged

Comment: @invrt - Without any other info it is hard to tell what is going wrong. Replicate the problem in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com) or similar sites and update your question with the link.

Comment: It seems to work when I execute the code a second time around, but yes...I'll try replicate the codebase

Comment: Here's there a codepen https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-blackwell-kd3nn

Comment: @invrt -  Check out my edited answer. Make those changes it should be working. Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-jennings-wlw8j

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of your problem is, you need to update every time your array `silos[]`  when you will get a new value for `available`. so the approach has given below.

```
  handleInputChange = e => {
    let input = e.target;
    let name = e.target.name;
    let value = input.value;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  silo_1Lookup = () => {
    let silosss = [...this.state.silos];
    const siloDepthFilling = {
      "0": "926",
      "0.5": "893",
      "1": "860",
      "1.5": "827",
      "2": "794",
      "2.5": "761",
      "3": "728",
      "3.5": "695",
      "4": "662",
      "4.5": "629",
      "5": "595"
    };

    // Push user input and available value in array
    silosss.push({
      userInput: this.state.userInput,
      available: siloDepthFilling[this.state.userInput]
    });

    // Finally update the state of both array and available value
    for(var item of silosss){
      this.setState({
        silos:silosss,
        available: item.available
      });
    }
  };
```

Finally, the output should be like that

[image]

Comment: Calling `setState()` in `for` loop here is inefficient and redundant because each iteration overrides previous state, and every time only the last iteration's values are set in the state.

Comment: @Nikhil: Thanks for your comment my concern was to show the available value is changing every time by setting state in output screen and pushing the value inside of an array. But of course, you are right. I agree. I don't want to edit my code because your comment can be another learning point for everyone from the above code..